# perl system command execution

Tags: perl, ssh

In the following code I need to print output from the variables `$stout`, `$stderr`. How can I do this and not without using `$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new`?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use File::Basename;
use lib "/nfs/site/proj/dpg/tools/lib/perl";
use Util;
use Getopt::Std;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;

my $host = 'someip.com.com';
my $pass = '';
my $user = '';
my $cmd  = 'pwd';

my($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = system('ssh someip.com cat /nfs/site/home/aa/test11.txt')        ;
if ($stdout) {
    print "Standard output is \n$stdout";
} elsif($stderr) {
    print "Standard error is \n$stderr";
}
```

Comment: According to the perldoc, system returns the exit code, so your command system('ssh...' will probably put the exit code is $stdout and leave $stderr and $exit undefined. What values are you expecting in those variables?

Comment: $stdout i am expecting the contents of the file  and if the file doest exist  i am expecting the error message in stderr

Comment: If you run it in backticks, rather than system, it will return the output, but I'm not sure how you distinguish between succesful output (the file) and unsuccesful output (an error message). $output = \`ssh someip.com...\`

Comment: Can we get some standard ouput or standarderr from backtiks or system command.

Comment: @ Matt Freake:I am implementing the way u have told but have accepted the other answer since it can be done that way too.No hard feelings :)

Comment: @ Rajeev. I'd say the other ways are better, so that's fine :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [IO::CaptureOutput](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/IO-CaptureOutput-1.1102/lib/IO/CaptureOutput.pod), its simpler.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture_exec);

my $cmd = "ssh someip.com cat /nfs/site/home/aa/test11.txt";
my ($stdout, $stderr, $success, $exitcode) = capture_exec( $cmd );
```

You can also use list parameters in `capture_exec` which I think is safer.

Answer (score 1):

[open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) allows you to read/write all handles:

```
use FileHandle;
use IPC::Open3;
my $cmd = "ssh someip.com cat /nfs/site/home/aa/test11.txt";
open3(\*GPW, \*GPR, \*GPE, "$cmd") or die "$cmd";
    # print GPW "write to ssh";
close GPW;
while (<GPR>) { 
  # read stdout
}
while (<GPE>) { 
  # read stderr
}
close GPR; close GPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a fan of `IPC::Run`:

```
use IPC::Run;

my $exitcode = run [ "ssh", "someip.com", "cat", ... ],
    undef, \my $stdout, \my $stderr;
```

At this point the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` results from the command will be stored in those two lexicals.

Though as a solution to the general issue of `ssh`'ing to a host and retrieving the contents of a file from within a Perl program, you might like `IPC::PerlSSH`:

```
use IPC::PerlSSH;

my $ips = IPC::PerlSSH->new( Host => "someip.com" );
$ips->use_library( "FS", qw( readfile ) );

my $content = $ips->call( "readfile", "/nfs/site/home/aa/test11.txt" );
```

The `$ips` object here will just hang around and allow for reuse to collect multiple files, execute other commands, and generally reuse the connection, rather than having to set up a new `ssh` connection every time.